# What does “they made bones” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Context: an old (70+ years old) Londoner is being interviewed about his past as a lighterman on the River Thames and says the following:

> Three big wharves there, they've flattened, all gone. One of them we called the stinker wharf. *They made bones*. It used to pen and ink when you went by there.

*Webster's Third* defines “to make bones” as “to show hesitation, uncertainty, or scruple,” but it doesn't seem to fit here. *Partridge Slang* says that “bone” could mean a marijuana/tobacco cigarette in the US; but it would be odd if an old Londoner used American slang terms.

Comment: This actually sounds more like Cockney than anything else.  To "pen and ink" is probably slang for "stink."  Cockney also uses phrases like "Get me a Britney" for "Get me a Beer" (Speer == Beer).  Good Luck on figuring out what it means though.

Comment: To my New York, second generation Italian-American ear, "make bones" evoked a completely different idea. Wikipedia quoting Peter Mass' excellent __Underboss__: 'Committing one's first contracted killing is referred to as "making your bones."' And the docks are a favorite place of the mob, So I immediately thought "somebody got whacked on the docks".

Comment: Sometimes something means just what it says. They made bones. From what? From carcasses. What did they use the bones for? Fertilizer. Blood and bone manure. It used to stink.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I sent an email to The Company of Watermen and Lightermen in London and asked them if they knew what a "stinker wharf" was and what it might mean to say that "they made bones" there.  Susan Fenwick replied

> a stinker wharf would have been a tannery (there were many along the
>   Thames) or perhaps a knackery (where they boiled down animal carcasses to
>   make glue, bone meal, etc) and so called because it smelled bad.

So it seems most likely that he meant something like [*bone meal*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bone+meal) when he said "they made bones."

As a side note, "make bones" (in the US anyway) can mean making money, and "bones" can refer to dice or dominoes as well.  I don't think either one of those fits here.

Comment: +1 for the research.  If this is the right interpretation (and it's a big _if_), the stinker wharf would be a knackery rather than a tannery.  There are no bones involved in tanning.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>"Dog and bones" is Cockney slang for *telephone*. Conceivably, this phrase had been shortened: *"they made bones"* could be translated as *they called (on the phone)*.</strike>

I would translate it as:

> Three big wharves have been demolished. One of them we called the stinker wharf. They <strike>called and</strike> complained because it stunk so much when you went by there.

**EDIT**

Actually, after a little more thinking, *make no bones about* is a synonym for *to have no objection to*. So while my translation is correct, I'm thinking "making bones" about the wharf is just a reversal of the phrase. They objected to the wharf.

More research.

> "Elizabeth was thus making huge bones of sending some £7000 over for the general purposes of the government in Ireland." -- [Richard Simpson's The School of Shakspere, 1878](http://books.google.ca/books?id=GLsHFixWu88C&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22Elizabeth+was+thus+making+huge+bones%22&source=bl&ots=4m_dGaoahN&sig=QUfgBEDPx7WpG5jDw5f0I44u3Y8&hl=en&ei=7IorTa3vNpq7nAe3-uCJAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22Elizabeth%20was%20thus%20making%20huge%20bones%22&f=false)

Comment: Interesting: so “to make bones” could be a contemporary reversal of “to make no bones”, or it could be an older usage which has now mostly disappeared?

Comment: I think this answer is completely wrong in assuming that OP's Cockney was using any variant of the idiomatic *"Make [no] bones about sth"*. He's obviously talking about the *primary activity* of the wharf, nothing to do with possible objections or directness of expression implicit in the idiom.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect the common meaning of *make [no] bones [about it]* is irrelevant here, and that he simply meant *they boiled bones* (to make glue, for example). Having driven past many old glue factories, I can confirm they do indeed *pen and ink* (stink).

**LATER** I'm still sure *make [no] bones [about it]* is irrelevant to OP's quoted usage. As is the well-known [rag and bone](http://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/dog_and_bone) *(phone)*. But it might be worth pointing out that "bone" is also Cockney rhyming slang for [throne](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Rag%20And%20Bone) *(toilet)*.

I admit it's not obvious to me why a toilet manufacturing plant should "stink". Unless they have exceptionally realistic on-site product testing methods, flushing straight into the Thames.

Comment: Boiling bones doesn't make them, it unmakes them. I think it more likely that this had something to do with fish, but most likely is about complaining.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that on a gloss of those meanings, "They made bones. It used to pen and ink when you went by there" would come across to the ear as "They would hesitate or complain because it stunk to go by there."

Comment: That doesn't stack up. In that case, who is 'they' in the sentence? Surely the lighterman would have said "We made bones".  I agree with those who interpret bones as literal.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the stinker wharf was a cannery? It would have appeared that they "made (fish) bones" as a by-product.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that someone might think of a knackery as a place where carcasses are turned into little more than bones; where the flesh is removed, rendrered and so on, just leaving bones. The word "made" might not be so literal. Sort of meaning that's what they did there, that's what the end result was, though not exactly the end product. They made the carcasses into bones, sort of. Made piles of bones, like making a mess.

Answer (score 0):

To make no bones about something is an old cockney term which means they will show no hesitation or uncertainty in doing something or saying something. My mother, father, grandparents used this saying to express the fact for example:
"If that person tries that again, I'll make no bones about it , I'll call the police" in other words they would not hesitate and you could certain that they would call the police/carry out a threat/meet out a punishment/etc.

And so to make bones is to wonder whether a certain action is right, to mull over or to be uncertain about doing something in other words the act of  thinking and pondering and uncertainty over whether to do something is to " make bones about "

Comment: There are those who say that the non-negated variant predates the one most people have heard today. I had to check that there is evidence that the non-negated variant has actually been used; one can't guarantee that a variant of an idiom is acceptable (spill no beans, take prisoners). But, as FumbleFingers has said, this idiom doesn't fit here. Rather, an old forgotten metonymy, as andy256 says above.